# Adding all files in git in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a solution with two projects. One of them is the main one and I have the 2nd one referenced. However, the 2nd one isn't added to the git changes, and when I push, it only pushes the main project, not the whole solution. How can I add the whole solution to be tracked by git ?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for a few reasons. Try the following:

- Check your `.gitignore` file and make sure you aren't ignoring the second project's folder
- Check that the second project folder is at the same level or underneath your `.git` folder
- Check that your `.git` folder isn't under your first project folder

**Edit:** Okay, based on your comment we know the second project is in the wrong place. You could move your second project underneath the first one but I wouldn't recommend it. The convention with Visual Studio is to have projects in separate folders either at the same level or underneath the .git folder. Depending on the complexity of your project it might just be easier to recreate the correct folder structure somewhere else and create a new repository.

See the [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) project on GitHub for an example of the project layout convention. The Dapper.sln file is at the same level as the `.git` folder and projects like Dapper.Contrib and Dapper.EntityFramework are in separate folders underneath that.

Comment: Indeed, it seems the .git folder, .gitattributes and .gitignore are only within the main project.  Could I just move the whole second project folder within the first one? Or would that break things

Comment: @crystyxn: I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks @Malice. I run into the same issue and after seeing this , I was able to fix it. I moved the .sln file to the root of the application and fixed the references in the .sln file, opened the solution, right clicked solution to make this a Git repository. Thanks a ton!!!!